# keep suggestion box relative to input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this `input box` and `an auto suggest div` which is shown when something is typed in. The `input box` has no fixed position and can be in different positions on the page.

How can I make it so the suggestion box `div` always appears `relative to the position` of the input. i.e the top left corner of the suggestion div is the same point as the bottom right corner of the input?

```
$('#textBox').on('keypress',function(){
    $('#suggestionBox').show();
  });

<input type = "text" id = "textBox" />  
<div id = "suggestionBox" style = "display:none;">
<ul>
 <li>suggestion</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `offset[Top|Left|Height]` properties of DOM0 :

```
$('#textBox').on('keypress',function(){
    $('#suggestionBox').css({
        position: "absolute",
        top: (this.offsetTop + this.offsetHeight) + "px",
        left: this.offsetLeft + "px"
    });
    $('#suggestionBox').show();
});
```

You can test on this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bAEyZ/).

Answer (score 1):

Have you Known about JQuery [AutoComplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) Feature..

It done the same thing you need. Try that.. It is simple..

It Enables users to quickly find and select from a per-populated list of values as they type, leveraging searching and filtering.